# wrong index of checkbox column in datagrid

Tags: checkbox, datagridview

I have this code to add a checkbox column in the third position, but the index  of this column(bloqueador) is 0 and not 3. What is wrong?

```
public void bloqselect()
{
 DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn chkSelect = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
 chkSelect.Selected = false;
 chkSelect.HeaderText = "Bloqueador";
 chkSelect.Name = "chkSelect";
 grid_lic.Columns.Insert(3, chkSelect);

 if (chkSelect.Selected == true)

    bloqueador = 1;
  else
   bloqueador = 0;
}
```

[checkbox column index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3gTj.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's a quirk about the loading order of the columns everyone learns the hard way. When you bind data to your DataGridView, the columns and their indices are resolved *after* the Form constructor has finished running - *always*. This is not true for manually added columns - they are resolved immediately.

Why does that matter? Let's say you have a DataSource that will resolve into the columns `Foo`, `Bar`, and `Baz`. Then you insert column `Add` into position 2. Your code to do so may look like:

```
dataGridView.DataSource = GetFooBarBazSource();
dataGridView.Columns.Insert(2, theAddColumn);
```

The column indices will depend directly on *when* you ran this code - in the Form constructor or after (let's say in `Form.Load`):

```
                 ╔═════╦═════╦═════╦═════╗
                 ║ Foo ║ Bar ║ Add ║ Baz ║
                 ╠═════╬═════╬═════╬═════╣
Form Constructor ║ 1   ║ 2   ║ 0   ║ 3   ║
Form_Load()      ║ 0   ║ 1   ║ 2   ║ 3   ║
                 ╚═════╩═════╩═════╩═════╝
```

If you want to fix the index order to be as expected, simply add an event handler for either `Form.Load` or `grid_lic.DataBindingComplete`, then make your call to `bloqselect()` within that handler.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, actually I was thinking in replacing the cells index by the new one provided by the adding of the checkbox column, but I've opted for another solution to include the checkbox column.