# DataGridViewButtonColumn is the last column as column 0

Tags: c#, sql, .net, datagridview, desktop

This is the code to fill the DataGridView Table from MSSqlLocalDB Table in my .NET C# Desktop Application.

```
sqlConnection.Open();
dt = new DataTable();
adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tbl_BarredList", sqlConnection);
adapter.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
sqlConnection.Close();

DataGridViewButtonColumn button = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
{
  button.Name = "Files Button";
  button.HeaderText = "Disciplinary Sheet";
  button.Text = "View Sheet";
  button.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
  this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(button);
}
dataGridView1.Columns[4].Visible = false; // is an image that shows when i click the button
```

When I update or insert any data into the database using values from the DataGridView I have to adjust for the DataGridViewButtonColumn as being column 0 even though it is the last column.
Is this because I set it manually and the other columns were set automatically? How can I fix this?

Not really sure what other code I need here to show what is happening...

EDIT: This seems to only happen if I have at least 1 row. If I have no rows at all it is fine. Obviously that cannot work.

Comment: It is difficult to understand why you … _”have to adjust for the DataGridViewButtonColumn as being column 0 even though it is the last column”_ … Since it is unknown what `dt` contains we can only assume that it actually has some columns. It is correct that if `dt` has columns then the line `this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(button);` in the posted code “should” put the column at the “end” and not the front. You may need to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) since the current code doesn’t reproduce the issue.

Comment: I've only come across this issue when building a `DataGridView` in the Form constructor.  In the constructor, code like yours will always produce a mismatch between the Column Index and [DisplayIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.displayindex?view=netframework-4.8) - even if you replace your `Add` with an `Insert`.  Try running your code in `Form.Load` instead.  [Check here for my explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34400651/3773066).

Comment: So to narrow it down a bit more, the column shift happens at both: `dataGridView1.CellEndEdit += DataGridView1_CellEndEdit; // and
            dataGridView1.RowPrePaint += DataGridView1_RowPrePaint;` POSTPAINT has the same outcome. I need to paint past due dates in red.